# LOAD DATA INFILE - FIELDS TERMINATED error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following load data infile query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE $csv INTO TABLE safety_quiz FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (first_name, last_name, person_id, quiz_result)
```

This produces the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '../import/import_20_01_2014.csv INTO TABLE safety_quiz FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ' at line 1

the csv format is:

```
Bob,Smith,123456789,100
Fred,Jones,987654321,100
```

the table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `safety_quiz` (
  `safety_quiz_pk` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `quiz_result` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`safety_quiz_pk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I have looked at other stackoverflow questions on the same issue, but I can't see where the error is...

**UPDATE**

Full code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])){

$type = explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name']);

if(strtolower(end($type)) == 'csv'){

$path = '../import/';   
$file_name = 'import_' . date('d_m_Y') . '.csv';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path . $file_name);

} else {
    $message = 'Only csv files can be uploaded.';   
}
} else {
    $message = 'You need to attach a csv file.';    

}

$csv = $path . $file_name;

$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv' INTO TABLE safety_quiz FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (first_name, last_name, person_id, quiz_result)";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

**WORKING CODE**

Looks like the path to the csv needs to be absolute (don't know why...), but this works:

```
$csv = '/var/www/html/labs/import/' . $file_name;

$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv' INTO TABLE safety_quiz FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (first_name, last_name, person_id, quiz_result)";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Can you try putting `$csv` in quotes `LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv'` or backticks? That may be the problem. Or try `LOAD DATA INFILE 'csv_file.csv'` (example filename) and `'\r\n'` is mostly used if you're on a Windows platform.

Comment: Plus, where is the `$csv` variable coming from and used like? You're not giving us much to go on. Something else could be breaking your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It would seem pretty obvious based on the error that it declares the file. And the issue you've described is likely the problem here as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please? Is it because the `$csv` isn't in quotes, or the `','` itself ? @Ohgodwhy

Comment: It's that the `$csv` variable isn't encapsulated correctly and therefore is interpreted literally.

Comment: Ok, which is why I asked the OP to try and wrap it in quotes. @Ohgodwhy --- Just haven't gotten any feedback other than yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example was taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html located near the bottom of the page.

```
"LOAD DATA INFILE '$myFile'" . " INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

and it shows the file's variable encapsulated in quotes.

Try the following:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv' INTO TABLE safety_quiz FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (first_name, last_name, person_id, quiz_result)
```

And as [`Ohgodwhy stated in a comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225650/load-data-infile-fields-terminated-error#comment31969969_21225650) is that the `$csv` variable isn't encapsulated correctly and therefore is interpreted literally.

Or encapsulated in single and double quotes with dots:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '".$csv."'
```

borrowed from [**this answer on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007097/)

Comment: putting $csv into quotes results in "Can't get stat of '/var/lib/import/import_20_01_2014.csv' (Errcode: 2)"

Comment: You can see from my OP that the variable $csv is being interpreted OK without quotes...

Comment: Then something else is breaking your code. Can you post your full code in your question? @PeterBrowne

Comment: specifying the full path to the csv works: LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/html/labs/import/import_20_01_2014.csv' INTO TABLE.  Why should I need to do this??

Comment: Well, you haven't shown me how you were using the `$csv` variable. If you haven't defined it anywhere, then that's the source of the problem. For example `$csv="/var/www/html/labs/import_20_01_2014.csv";` which is how it would be used if setting/using it from a variable. @PeterBrowne but in your case, I think you're doing this straight from PHPadmin or other similar program?

Comment: No, the code above is a php form that uploads the csv into a folder ('import') then does the query to put the csv contents into a table.  The path specified is the upload path which is relative to the form.  This should work without having to specify the full server path...  You can see that the path was actually specified in the code with $path and the path shows OK in the original error.  Nonetheless, you are correct that the vaiable for the csv needs to be encaspulated in quotes...so I'll give you the answer on that ;->  still don't know why I have to specify the full server path though...

Comment: Did you try `$csv = '$path' . $file_name;` @PeterBrowne

Comment: Yes I saw it, and it reads as `$csv = $path . $file_name;` without the quotes around `$path` and was wondering if that worked instead `$csv = '$path' . $file_name;` @PeterBrowne